# wxpython-can we add ok button on pybusyinfo dialog?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have created pybusyinfo dialog to display message and after 30 secs of sleep it will automatically close.

Now i need to add ok button in that dialog to get user input and they are not pressed the button the dialog should close in 30secs.

Can we add that button into wx.lib.agw.pybusyinfo dialog ?

Or is there any other dialog of wx widgets will automatically close after sometime?

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.pybusyinfo as PBI
retVal = showmsg("dialog will be closed in 30 secs...")
time.sleep(30)
retVal = None

def showmsg(msg):
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    title = 'Message!'
    retVal = PBI.PyBusyInfo(msg, title=title)
    return retVal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own busy dialog which contains a gauge to show that it is busy.
Use a `wxTimer` to loop the guage.
This should get you started:

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Busy Dialog",size=(500,200))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(400,100),style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.VSCROLL)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Click me")
        sizer.Add(self.log, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

    def OnButton(self,event):
        dlg = Busy(parent = self.panel) 
        dlg.ShowModal()
        if dlg.result_text:
            self.log.AppendText("Text Input: "+dlg.result_text+"\n")
        dlg.Destroy()

class Busy(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Busy", size= (420,240))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY)
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Input", pos=(20,20))
        self.textinput = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="", pos=(80,20), size=(300,-1))
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self.panel,size=(300,20),pos=(80,80), style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        self.livelabel = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Time to live:", pos=(80,110))
        self.lltime = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="30", pos=(160,110))
        self.saveButton =wx.Button(self.panel, label="Save Input", pos=(80,160))
        self.closeButton =wx.Button(self.panel, label="Cancel", pos=(180,160))
        self.timeoutButton =wx.Button(self.panel, label="Timer Off", pos=(280,160))
        self.saveButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SaveBusyString)
        self.closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)
        self.timeoutButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnNoTimeout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnQuit)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER,self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.lifetimer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER,self.OnLifeTimer, self.lifetimer)
        self.timer.Start(100)
        self.lifetimer.Start(1000)
        self.timeoutbutton_pressed = False
        self.gauge.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 127, 255, 255)) #Slate Blue
        self.gauge.SetRange(100)
        self.gauge.SetValue(0)
        self.life = 30
        self.direction = 1
        self.Show()

    def OnTimer(self, evt): #Update gauge
        x = int(self.gauge.GetValue())
        if x == 0:
            self.direction = 1
        elif x == 100:
            self.direction = -1
        x+=self.direction
        self.gauge.SetValue(x)

    def OnLifeTimer(self, evt): #Update time to live
        if self.timeoutbutton_pressed == True:
            return
        self.life -= 1
        self.lltime.SetLabelText(str(self.life))
        if self.life < 1:
            self.OnQuit(None)

    def OnNoTimeout(self, evt): # toggle time to live
        if self.timeoutbutton_pressed == False:
            self.timeoutbutton_pressed = True
            self.timeoutButton.SetLabel("Timer On")
        else:
            self.timeoutbutton_pressed = False
            self.timeoutButton.SetLabel("Timer Off")

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.timer.Stop()
        self.lifetimer.Stop()
        self.result_text = None
        self.Destroy()

    def SaveBusyString(self, event): # return input
        self.result_text = self.textinput.GetValue()
        self.timer.Stop()
        self.lifetimer.Stop()
        self.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Edit:
You need a frame because the dialog to requires a parent, so the easiest way is to make a frame that you cannot see.
Lose the `MyFrame` class in the above and change the `app` section of code to something like this:

```
app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None,-1,"",size=(1,1))
frame.Show()
dlg = Busy(parent = frame)
dlg.ShowModal()
print dlg.result_text # Do whatever here with the result I just print it
dlg.Destroy()
```

Comment: Oh this is great..Working like charming..But I dont want Frame.Just dialog.Can I get return value from dialog without Frame?

Comment: You need the `busy` class and the code defined in the `OnButton` section, although you will need to set the `parent` parameter to a value relevant to your code.

Comment: I want to directly open busy dialog and click any button and get the value out of class to pass as parameter to some other function..Can you help me to get that pls?

Comment: ..getting "PyDeadObjectError" on print dlg.result_text :-(

Comment: You will need to post your code in an edit to your question, I can't guess what you're doing ;)